# use stripe-connect in lumen laravel , installation issue

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, lumen

I am developing backend in a lumen and want to integrate stripe connect.
I am using `composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect` this library for stripe connect.

I have a question regarding installation of laravel-stripe-connect,
as previously I was using stripe and it was working fine but as per requirement I want to use stripeConnect instead of a stripe.

now when I run this `composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect` it shows me the following error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect ^0.2.1 -> satisfiable by rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect[v0.2.1].
- rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect v0.2.1 requires stripe/stripe-php ^5.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v5.0.0, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.3.0, v5.4.0, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.6.0, v5.7.0, v5.8.0, v5.9.0, v5.9.1, v5.9.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{   
          "name": "laravel/lumen",    
          "description": "The Laravel Lumen  Framework.",    
          "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],       
          "license": "MIT",    
          "type": "project",    
          "require": {
              "php": ">=5.6.4",
              "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.*",
              "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
              "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0@dev",
              "illuminate/mail": "^5.5",
              "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.21"    
          },    
          "require-dev": {
              "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
              "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
              "mockery/mockery": "~0.9"    
          },
         "autoload": {
              "psr-4": {
                  "App\\": "app/"
               }
         },    
         "autoload-dev": {
              "classmap": [
                 "tests/",
                 "database/"
               ]    
         },    
         "scripts": {
              "post-root-package-install": [
                  "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
               ]    
         },
         "minimum-stability": "dev",    
         "prefer-stable": true,    
         "optimize-autoloader": true    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `"stripe/stripe-php": "^6.21"` to `"stripe/stripe-php": "^5.9"`, since the libary you try to import uses the `^5.0` tag it will only allow builds tagged with the format 5.x. Your requirement goes above this with at least 6.21, so the `require` fails.